# How to pause network requests when they fail/there is no internet and execute when internet is available?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, altbeacon

I am working on a React Native + redux App. The app uses a foreground service in android which scans for BLE beacons. The service sends events when it discovers a beacon to react-native via the bridge, upon receiving the event an API call to fetch relevant information is done.

The problem is when there is no internet and a beacon is discovered. I am using react-native-storage to store found beacons.

```
storage.save({
key: 'places', // Note: Do not use underscore("_") in key!
id: beacons.uuid,
data: {
  uuid: beacons.uuid.toString(),
  minor: parseInt(beacons.minor, 10),
  major: parseInt(beacons.major, 10),
},

// if expires not specified, the defaultExpires will be applied instead.
// if set to null, then it will never expire.
expires: null,
});
```

If the beacon is out of range, I remove the beacon from the storage. When the app restarts I check whether the storage has some beacons and make API calls for those beacons.

If there is no internet, the request fails. Is there a way to pause the request and re-execute it when there is internet?

Comment: have you tried looking into redux saga ?

Comment: @InquisitiveGirl I'm using Redux Saga, but how do I retry requests if they fail due to no internet connection?